# Data is not insert to the position input by the user in linked list Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently working on a linked list that need to insert and delete data from the position that user input. However, I have met some error with insertion. I follow the code that I found online and I don't know where is the problem, the data that I enter did not insert to the linked list, everytime I display the linked list it shows me NULL even I do have insert some data in it.

Here is my code for insertion:

```
    public void addItemRequest(Node head, int item, int position)
    {
    Node prevNode = head; 
    Node newNode = new Node(item,null); 

    if (head==null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (position == 0)
    {
        newNode.next = head; 
        return;
    }    

    int count = 0;
    while (count < position -1 && head.next != null)
    {
        head = head.next;        
        count++;       
    }

    Node currNode = head.next;
    head.next = newNode;
    head = head.next;
    head.next = currNode;      
    return;
}
```

Here is my code for Node class:

```
class Node{
int num;
Node next;

Node()
{
    num=0;
    next=null;
}

Node(int num, Node next)
{
    this.num=num;
    this.next=next;
}

int getNum()
{
    return num;
}

Node getNext()
{
    return next;   
}

void setNext(Node next)
{
    this.next=next;
}
}
```

I hope someone could tell me what is the problem here, thanks.

Comment: Please post the code for your `Node` constructor...

Comment: Check your Node class, probably there is a method that throws the mentioned exception.

Comment: @beatrice oh yes there it is. I have deleted it and change my code to Node newNode = new Node(item,null). But it still didn't store the data in the list, why?

Comment: @brso05 done edited, and new problem occurs....

Comment: You `addItemRequest` method have signature that prohibit to add node at `0` position. And of cource you cant add anything to empty list because empty list is just `null` for your implementation.

Comment: @talex May I know how to solve that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You have to make `head` as a global variable then only it will work**

Go easy with only one temp node that is new

```
public void addItemRequest(Node head, int item, int position)
{
    Node prevNode = head; 
    Node newNode = new Node(item,null); 

    if (head==null)
    {
        head=newNode; 
        return;
    }

    if (position == 0)
    {
        newNode.next = head; 
        head = newNode; 
        return;
    }    

    int count = 0;
    while (count < position -1 && head.next != null)
    {
        prevNode = prevNode.next;        
        count++;       
    }
    newNode.next = prevNode.next;
    prevNode.next = newNode;      
    return;
}
```

Check now. I have corrected the answer. `head=newNode;` has to added in `if (position == 0)`

If you really want to appreciate accept the answer and upvote it. So that someone like you can also find the solution easily.

Comment: `head = newNode;` doesn't have any sense it is assignment to local variable.

Comment: any way thanks for your comments and that I have updated it accordingly

Comment: Simple advice to make `head` global may not help. It is plainly impossible to help OP with information that he gave. This doesn't mean you should give such broad recommendation. It only make sings worse for such inexperienced person as OP.

Comment: I dont know one thing. You know that the info on the question is insufficient. why are u down voting the answer and not the question. perhaps you could have recommended an edit in the question, why are you hanging on the answer?

Comment: Because I'm too lazy to explain OP his problems.

Comment: but this is not the solution at all. this is not how SO works right. if you think this as unapropriate qustion then you should down vote or flag in question not on answers